# How do you clean a juju controller disk or make it larger?

Tags: juju

My juju controllers appear to be defaulting to a 10GB root disk.  I am running out of disk space on the controller.  I have 6.7GB in /var/lib/juju/db.  Is there a way to reduce the disk usage on this?  If not, can I make the root disk larger?  What are my options?

I have already cleared out kernel updates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know yet about cleaning the database, but I did figure out how to make the root file system larger.  My cloud structure is vmware and I made the virtual disk larger and rebooted the controller.  The default behaviour for the cloud-init process is to expand the root partition if the disk grows and to resize the root file system to match.